# Regex in sed statement

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm having some problems with the following expression from a bash script:

```
ipreg=^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$

sed -i 's/\"https:\/\/'$ipreg':9999\",/\"https:\/\/'${newip}':9999\",/g' /usr/share/config.file
```

Sed can't find the old Ip address with the var ipreg, but if i put in the exact address it does get replaced with the new IP.

Comment: This is because you are using single quotes in your `sed` command and the variable is not expanded. Just change `sed '...'` for `sed "..."`.

Comment: @fedorqui I don't think this is the only thing causing OP's problem. The slashes used as separator for `s/.../.../` are also present in `https//`. He should use `s:...:...:` (or any non-slash sign) instead

Comment: Could you show a sample of your `/usr/share/config.file` file ?

Comment: here are some lines of the file..
*/
"https://10.10.10.10:9999",
/** @scratch /configuration/config.js/5
*
   * ==== default_route
   *

Comment: When i remove '$ipreg' and run sed -i 's/\"https:\/\/10.10.10.10.:9999\",/\"https:\/\/'${newip}':9999\",/g' /usr/share/config.file it is working

Comment: @Ipetrov80 you should edit your question to add your sample input.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making this too complex.  I don't see a reason to match IPv4 addresses so tightly.

Why not simplify it a bit like this:

```
sed -i "s|https://[0-9.]*:9999|https://$newip:9999|" /usr/share/config.file
```

Also, you probably don't want anchors in your regex, since it's in the middle of a string.  `^` matches the beginning of a line and `$` matches the end - you don't want those in the middle of your match pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Many `sed` dialects do not support `{1,3}` repetition. Try with backslashes before the curlies, and/or see if your `sed` has an `-r` or `-E` option to enable Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax.

In the worst case, just write the repetitions in longhand, or maybe simplify them to just `*` if you can live with the rather remote possibility for false positives.

As an aside, you should use quotes aroind anything which contains shell metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

This could work, taking into account the comment of tripleee.

```
$ cat config.file 
.. / "https://10.10.10.10:9999";, /* @scratch /configuration/config.js/5 * * ==== default_route *
$ cat changeip.sh 
#!/bin/bash
ipreg='[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
newip='127.0.0.1'
sed -ri 's/"https:\/\/'"${ipreg}"':9999"/"https:\/\/'"${newip}"':9999"/' "$1"
cat "$1"
$ ./changeip.sh config.file 
.. / "https://127.0.0.1:9999";, /* @scratch /configuration/config.js/5 * * ==== default_route *
```

Does the IP occur more than once? Only than you will need the global option.